# Google Sheets determining if sheet is protected via scripting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a script for a Spreadsheet with a lot of sheets. After a sheet is completed, it is duplicated and set to protected. I would like my script to run during onEdit() on any sheet which is not protected. Is there a way to determine if a sheet is protected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using getProtections:

```
 function onEdit(e) {
     var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
     var protect = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)
     if (protect != "Protection") {
         // Run your code here. For example:
         SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").setValue("Unprotected");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function named `onEdit(e)` and using the Spreadsheet `getSheets()` method you can access all sheets and determine if they have a protectionType of SHEET. If they do then just return immediate and don't process them in the `onEdit(e)`.  The current sheet name can be determined using this code `e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()`.